# Create an obstacle in which the player needs to respond to move ahead

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm pretty new to Unity 2d. How can I create a **question** as an **obstacle** for a moving character in Unity 2d?

Please note that the questions can be up to 5 in number, appearing as the character forges ahead and also would have options in which the player most select one to move. The final result may count at the end or he may loose a life if he chooses the wrong option.

Comment: I'd use the unityanswers forum if i were you, this one is for quite strict it's for hyper complex topics mostly.

Comment: @comprehensible: simple or beginner questions are very welcome here. However, they must be answerable and specific, and thus "how do I design my system" questions are too broad. Torera, if you can add in some code you have so far, this might aid your potential helpers.

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to know exactly what you want as you don't have any code to review, but something like this should work:

---

In your script controlling the player:

```
public bool canMove = true;

if(canMove) {
//Your code allowing the player to move
}
```

In your script governing the obstacles:

```
public PlayerController playerController;

public bool didSolveCorrectly;
public int punishments;

void StartObstacle(int type) {
    playerController.canMove = false; 

    switch (type) {
    //Cases and other stuff about the puzzles. I recommend making methods later on in the code and calling them here, so that it's more organized.
    }
}

void CompleteObstacle(bool correct, int punishmentType) {
    if (correct) {
        playerController.canMove = true;
    }
    else {
        switch (punishmentType) {
            //More cases governing what should happen to the player if they failed the question
        }
    }
}
```

This is a VERY broad answer to our question, and of course you need to edit it to fit what you need.